# How to separate hyperlinks on html page

Tags: html, hyperlink

I have a html page with close to 100 hyperlinks.

Is there a way to separate all those links and give me 100 different html files?

Answer (score 1):

In such case dynamic sites are better rather than creating 100 different files for every link.
It is assumed that most of the pages would have same layout. Dynamic site would take only few lines of coding and few files to do so.